# HTML Form Method Post with Golang

Tags: html, forms, go, post, methods

So, I have this form in an html. It is intended to have a POST request to `/subscribe` page:

```
<html>
  <form action="/subscribe" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Willy"/><br/>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Warmwood"/><br/>
    Email: <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="willy.warwood@gmail.com"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
</html>
```

Then, I have this router in golang:

```
http.HandleFunc("/subscribe/", SubscribeHandler)
```

And this handler in golang:

```
func SubscribeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println(r.Method)
}
```

But the problem is, it always print `GET`.

How to post the form, so the value of `r.Method` is `POST`?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this handler is being called for the form submit? The handler is bound to `/subscribe/` but your form is pointed at `/subscribe`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the docs:

> If a subtree has been registered and a request is received naming the subtree root without its trailing slash, ServeMux redirects that request to the subtree root (adding the trailing slash). This behavior can be overridden with a separate registration for the path without the trailing slash.

Because you registered `"/subscribe/"`, *with* the trailing slash, it is registered as a subtree.  Again, per the docs:

> a pattern ending in a slash names a rooted subtree

Because an HTTP redirect is (in practice) always a GET request, the method after the redirect is of course a GET.  You can see that a real redirect is happening in this example: https://play.golang.org/p/OcEhVDosTNf

The solution is to either register both:

```
http.HandleFunc("/subscribe/", SubscribeHandler)
http.HandleFunc("/subscribe", SubscribeHandler)
```

Or point your form to the one with a `/`:

```
<form action="/subscribe/" method="post">
```

Comment: I was spending my time figuring out why the form always sent a `get` request. Now, I know it is happening because the request is redirected. Good demo example though. Thanks!